# Repetir elemento com ng-Repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Eu tenho um formulário, este o qual pode ser inserido mais um grupo de "Nome" e "Agência" somente ao clicar ao botão. Estou usando AngularJS e ng-Repeat para repetir os campos no momento em que clica em *+*. Porém, a lista de nomes das Agências "perde" no momento em que insiro um novo contato.
Como faço para que essa lista "persista"? 
****** #select-tools refere-se ao Campo "Buscar agência" 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando insiro mais um não há nenhum elemento na lista
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
        <h4>Contatos</h4>
        <div ng-repeat="contato in contatos" class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Nome:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="contato.nome">
            </div>
          <div class="form-group">
                <h4>Ag&ecirc;ncia</h4>
                <div class="control-group">
                <select ng-options="agencia.nome for agencia in listaAgencias" class="demo-default" placeholder="Selecionar a ag&ecirc;ncia..." selectize>
          </select>
                </div>
        </div>
            </div>
        <div align="right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" ng-click="novoContato()">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" ng-click="excluirContato()"
                    ng-disabled="contatosVazio()">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
            </div>
```

Controller.js

```
oknok.controller('veiculoController', function ($scope, veiculosAPI, agenciasAPI) {
    agenciasAPI.getAgencias().success(function (data) {
        var embedded = data._embedded;
        $scope.listaAgencias = embedded.agencias;
        $('#select-tools').selectize({
            maxItems: null,
            valueField: 'nome',
            labelField: 'nome',
            searchField: 'nome',
            options: embedded.agencias,
            create: false
        });
    }).catch(function (error) {
        alert("Erro ao obter listagem de agencias");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
    $scope.contatos = [{
        nome: "",
        dados: []
    }];

    $scope.cancelar = function () {
        window.location.href = "/"
    };

    $scope.novoContato = function () {
        $scope.contatos.push({
            nome: "",
            email: ""
        });
    };

    $scope.excluirContato = function () {
        var ultimoItem = $scope.contatos.length - 1;
        $scope.contatos.splice(ultimoItem);
    };

    $scope.contatosVazio = function () {
        if (!($scope.contatos.length <= 1)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    };

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que o *ng-repeat* está criando um escopo diferente para cada instância de `agencia`, e cada um possui uma cópia diferente de `listaAgencias`.

Inicialize a variável de escopo logo no início do *controller*, de maneira que os subescopos possam acessá-lo de maneira compartilhada:

```
oknok.controller('veiculoController', function ($scope, veiculosAPI, agenciasAPI) {
    agenciasAPI.getAgencias().success(function (data) {

        $scope.listaAgencias = [];

        var embedded = data._embedded;
        [...]
```

Comment: Esse select é responsável somente por outro campo, o campo que está com problema é independente deste código. A única linha que inicializa o meu campo é: `<select ng-options="agencia.nome for agencia in listaAgencias" class="demo-default" placeholder="Selecionar a ag&ecirc;ncia..." selectize>`

Comment: @DanielaMarquesdeMorais Ah, entendo - obrigado pelo esclarecimento. Eu alterei a resposta para cobrir outra possibilidade.